# generate a dataframe of parameter values

Tags: r, parameters, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to generate a dataframe of parameter values for a sensitivity analysis where each row is a parameter space. I'd like to be able to automate the generation of the dataframe such that each parameter is varied by -10% and +10% whilst all the other values are kept the same (see below example of desired df). Does anyone know how I can do this? I feel like the answer is obvious, but really can't see what it is!

Example of desired df:

```
a <- c(10,9,11,10,10,10,10,10,10)
b <- c(20,20,20,18,22,20,20,20,20)
c <- c(30,30,30,30,30,27,33,30,30)
d <- c(40,40,40,40,40,40,40,36,44)

parms <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will get you the "one parameter changing at a time" pattern you showed in your example.

```
params <- c(a = 10, b = 20, c = 30, d = 40)

builder_func <- function(params) {
  opts <- map_df(params, ~c(., .*.9, .*1.1))
  stocks <- map_df(params, ~rep(., 3))

  map_df(names(opts),
      ~ bind_cols(
        opts[.],
        stocks[. != names(stocks)]
      )) %>%  
        unique()
}

builder_func(params)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
a     b     c     d
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    20    30    40
2     9    20    30    40
3    11    20    30    40
4    10    18    30    40
5    10    22    30    40
6    10    20    27    40
7    10    20    33    40
8    10    20    30    36
9    10    20    30    44
```

Sorry I missed that nuance the first time I read your question. Let me know if something isn't quit right...

Comment: as the above answer this does do something similar to what I want, but not exactly. The desired result for these example parameters is exactly what I've put in the example data.

Comment: is there a pattern to your desired out? If you need specific values you might already have the best solution

Comment: the pattern isn't important, it's just important that each parameter is changed one by one -10% and +10%, whilst all of the other parameters remain the same (as in example).

Answer (score 1):

I think the function `expand.grid` is what you are looking for.

```
a <- c(9,10,11)
b <- c(18,20,22)
c <- c(27,30,33)
d <- c(36,40,44)
test <- expand.grid(a,b,c,d)
```

To automate the first part (variation by 10% around center value) you may use this approach:

```
library(magrittr)
vary_around_center <- function(center){
  c(center*0.9, center, center*1.1)
}

c(10,20,30,40) %>% 
  lapply(vary_around_center) %>% 
  expand.grid
```

Comment: I like this approach, but it doesn't do exactly what I need it to as it just provides every combination of all variables. Instead, I'd like all variables set to their normal value and then each one changed by -/+10% while all the others stay the same. If you look at the example dataset, I've given the exact desired result for this set of parameters.